# Unable to log in to Azure VM running in Hyper-V

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, azure, linux-on-azure

I have a virtual machine hosted in azure. I want to run this machine locally to make some tests so I downloaded the VHD image and created a VM in Hyper-V

[image]

The problem is that I cannot log in to this machine, even though I am using the same login I use to log in via rsh when it runs in azure:

[image]

Comment: In my lab, I can use my account to login it, which account are you use?

Comment: You could just reset the password (There is a guide over here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download VHD from Azure VM(ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS), and run it on Hyper-v, I can use my original account to login it:

[image]

Could you please tell me which account are you use to login? By default, we can't use root to login it.
By the way, several mouths ago, I can't use original account to login this VM on Hyper-v. If your VM create in that time, we should use OS file to to reset the password, or we create a new Ubuntu and download it again.

Comment: Hi @Jason Ye. I didn't login to "root", but to the user I set up when I initialized the virtual machine (the one that appears when you click in the "Connect" button in the portal. I tried with a different account and the result is the same: I can log in to the online VM but I cannot login to the image I downloaded.

Comment: Actually, I could log in to another account, unfortunately it's one with very limited privileges. I'll grant sufficient permissions to it in the online VM and i'll download a new image (which is quite annoying, it's 30GB and Microsoft Azure makes cash every time I need to do this type of things)